# Pine Script - Cannot call 'alertcondition' with 'message'=series[string]. The argument should be of type: const string

Tags: pine-script

I want my pine script to alert me when the RSI value is either overbought or oversold and in the alert message I want it to tell me the RSI value. Here's a piece of my script:

```
//RSI Value
rsiValue = rsi(src, len)
rsiOverbought = barssince(rsiValue > overbought) == 1
rsiOversold = barssince(rsiValue < oversold) == 1

//Alerts
alertcondition(condition=(rsiOverbought or rsiOversold), title="RSI Overbought or Oversold", message = "RSI Overbought or Oversold (RSI is " + tostring(rsiValue, "#.00)"))
```

When I save the script, I always get this error message:

`Cannot call 'alertcondition' with 'message'=series[string]. The argument should be of type: const string`

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

alertcondition is limited to plotted values for variable strings. You can only build strings this way with alert(). For more information about placeholders and using plots as variables in alertcondition() string, [visit this URL](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000531021)